# Incomprehensible results with python readline(s)

Tags: python, file, external

Here are the contents of res.txt

```
one  
two  
three
four
```

Here is my code:

```
inputlist = open ('res.txt' , 'r')

a = inputlist.readline(3)
b = inputlist.readlines()
print a, b
```

here is the result:

```
one ['\n', 'two\n', 'three\n', 'four']
```

Are these two methods not designed for python 2.7? The .txt is saved on Lubuntu with Leafpad. What's happening?

PS: I know that the second is a list, but it seems that the first method has grabbed out of it the first line, while it was supposed to just read the third line...

Answer (score 0):

If you read what `readline` actually does, it that it takes a size of how much it should read. IE, you called `a = inputlist.readline(3)`, now you have read the first 3 chars at the line of the reading head.

Left is not the newline symbol on the first line, which reads as its own line, so doing a `readlines` from here will produce you list, `['\n', 'two\n', 'three\n', 'four']`

For the result you want, you should probalby read the lines first, and then extract line no. 3;

```
lines = inputlist.readlines()
a = lines[2] # third line has index 2
b = lines
print a, b
```

[Readline tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The [readline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.readline) argument is a size argument of the maximum bytes to read, not index of the line to read...

In your example, your read the 3rd first bytes => "one"
Then you call readlines, it returns the '\n' after "one" and all the remaining lines...